# Missing Puppet provider for types group and user

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I installed Puppet 5 on an CentOS 7 machine from `https://yum.puppet.com/puppet/`. The installation was successful and I can run `puppet apply` for a simple manifest like this one:

```
file {'/tmp/example-ip':
    ensure  => present,
    mode    => '0644',
    content => "Here is my Public IP Address: ${ipaddress_eth0}.\n",
}
```

But if I try to create a user and group via Puppet I always get the following erorr messages:

```
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for user
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for group
```

Here is the manifest which produces these errors:

```
group { 'team-berlin':
  ensure => present,
}

group { 'team-london':
  ensure => present,
}
```

The types user and group should be present according to the output of `puppet resource`:

```
$ puppet resource --types
...
file
filebucket
group
host
...
tidy
user
...
```

Why do I get this error messages? What did I miss?

Comment: Please show the user/group definition from your manifest

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Did you run 'puppet apply' as root? Permission problem (for none root user) can trigger such issues.

Comment: Thanks. I feel so stupid. Can you post your hint as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use resources like user/group (which depend on binaries like useradd/groupadd) you must run `puppet apply` as root or with root-privileges.